# Normal map - UV Island creates diffrent brightness

Tags: uv, normals, baking, normal-map

I've been just starting blender these days .

I got my normal map from texture map through baking process and when I use that normal map , there are some kinds of borders between uv islands (seems like it has different brightness ..)

I searched for this problem but still I'm not sure what is the main reason causing this problem

[image]

So this is the result which I've got

And this is a normal map 
[image]
I just assume that process which I get normal map from texture map made some problems ..

If this is a duplicated quistion , sorry then .

and thanks in advance

Just let me know if .blend file is needed

Comment: For Cycles: Make sure you're using the [Normal Map Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/vector/normal_map.html) correctly, and that the normal map image is set to [Non-Color Data](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4866/what-exactly-does-the-non-color-data-option-for-image-environment-textures-do/4868).

Comment: I already set that but it still can't fix my problem ;(

Comment: Was the normal map baked in tangent space? And is it now being mapped in tangent space? Those settings need to match up, otherwise you will get shading problems at the seams.

Comment: I baked in tanget space and it 's also mapped in tangent space .. I may guess something wrong in my uv map . Anyway I changed tangent space to object space when baking, and it seems like the problem is solved . However still don't know exactly what the problem is.   My baking process is this - 1) import texture map to a plane and subdivide it , 2) add decimation modifier and subdivision surface modifier 3) add new plane and bake normal map  from previous plane to new plane .   Any problems during this process??

Comment: Some more info that might help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59107/bake-normal-space-camera-vs-world-vs-object-vs-tangent

Comment: Thank you for your help . I found the reason at the end. The normal map was a problem . I made an image with setting (32 bit Float) before, and when I unchecked it and made an image, normal was baked well . Don't know exactly well why it happens..(Just one thing .. Previous normal map was bit brighter than latter normal map ) I will try to figure it out ASAP . Anyway thanks Mentalist