# The Normal maps turned darker than on the other side

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normal-map

I'm studying on the new update of the 3d program, Blender 2.8. And I attempted to bake a normal map for the lowpolied twin angelic wings from the highpolied. I set up the nodes and adjusted the RGB settings on the normal maps and as you see here down below that on material mode the normals were completely fine and had no differences on either side. [image] But when I turn on rendered cycle mode/rendered it, The right side of the wing is darker than the left side.[image] I checked the normals on edit mode and made sure that the normals were pointing outwards. But even then, the normals on the right side of the wing acted like it was a shadow. And remember that I mirrored lowpolyied mesh and the normals from both the left and right side of the highpolied were baked separately. Here's the node trees i set up for both sides of the lowpolied.

Left side: [image]
[image]

Right side: [image]
[image]
 So here's the question, What the living hell did I do wrong?

EDIT: Hi! I think I discovered something recently and I think what the problem is: [image]
This is the highres model here and if you look a little bit closer, you can see the lightings on the right side of the wing is a lot different from the left side, especially the outer parts of it. So if you know what the solution is to fix it, let me know.

Comment: You've baked a tangent space normal map, but it's currently configured as *Object Space* in the *Normal Map* node.

Comment: So what's the difference between "Tangent Space" and "Object Space"?

Comment: And nope, I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: For the difference see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59107/bake-normal-space-camera-vs-world-vs-object-vs-tangent

Comment: I'm still getting the same result.